# SumatraPDF via scoop: how to set as default application?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, package-management, scoop

Recently I have been trying out [Scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop), which seems great for things like nodejs, yarn, git, etc.. But I am having troubles with applications that would otherwise also create file associations. Like for example when I install Sumatra PDF via scoop.

Even when I manually choose the shim location of the executable and choose "always open ..." - the next time I try to open a PDF it still opens up with Windows Edge (the default application for PDFs under Windows 10).

Is there a more general way to handle file associations and file icons, when installing applications via scoop?

Answer (score 1):

When we install the application-SumatraPDF, we can open Settings->Apps->Default apps->choose default apps by file type->find .PDF ->click Choose a default->select SumatraPDF.

[image]

Comment: That does not work unfortunately. It always resets to "Microsoft Edge" because Windows always says "There was a problem with 'sumatrapdf.exe'", even though by itself is working fine. But may be that was another problem entirely.